# My data got unicoded! How to fix this?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, unicode, distributed-computing

Following the [Prepare my bigdata with Spark via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401690/prepare-my-bigdata-with-spark-via-python) question, I did:

```
data = data.map(lambda x: (x[0], json.loads(x[1])))
r = data.flatMap(lambda x: ((a,x[0]) for a in x[1]))
r2 = r.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0],tuple(x[1])[:150]))
r2.saveAsTextFile('foo')
```

Now when I read it like:

```
data = sc.textFile('foo')
dataList = data.collect()
```

I get:

```
In [4]: dataList[8191][0]
Out[4]: u'('

In [5]: dataList[8191]
Out[5]: u"(5119, (u'5873341528', u'8599419601', u'5155716547'))"

In [6]: len(dataList[8191][1])
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: dataList[8191][1]
Out[7]: u'5'
```

while the data were meant to be accessed like the first item to be 5119, and the second the tuple. I see the unicode sign there, where I didn't asked for it..

Any ideas?

Comment: You saved the data as a text file, what did you expect?

Comment: Use serialization. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.pickleFile

Comment: Thank you very much @juanpa.arrivillaga, but the dupe worked fine! :)